# Do Java agents affect the JVM classpath?

Tags: java, jvm, agent

Do agents (-javaagent:agent.jar) affect the classpath of the JVM they are attached to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agent classes are loaded by the system class loader.

Agents may also append other JARs to bootstrap classpath or system classpath by calling [Instrumentation.appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#appendToBootstrapClassLoaderSearch-java.util.jar.JarFile-) or [Instrumentation.appendToSystemClassLoaderSearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#appendToSystemClassLoaderSearch-java.util.jar.JarFile-) respectively.